# how to get rid of empy posts in in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the following liquid code to display a list of categories and list of title of posts under each category.

```
{% for category in site.categories   %}
<a name="{{ category | first }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
<ul>
{% for posts in category  %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">a{{ post.title }}a</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

this display the list of posts as in the attached image
[output of the above Liquid code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGsMj.png)

As you can see in the pic there are two categories "Markdown" and "temp". Under each category titles of the posts are listed. But here the first list item in each category shows empty. Could you tell me how can I get rid of this empty list item and display everything else as in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the title:

```
{% for category in site.categories   %}
<a name="{{ category | first }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
<ul>
{% for posts in category  %}
    {% for post in posts %}

        {% assign title_length=post.title | size %}
        {% if title_length > 0 %}

        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">a{{ post.title }}a</a></li>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```